# How to get filtered elements of an array field using $filter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a train collection in MongoDB which has following rows:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("594a441fcbd8f815dc42436d"),
        "trainnum" : "011Ф",
        "startplace" : "Tashkent",
        "destination" : "Samarkand",
        "weeks" : [
                "1",
                "2",
                "3"
        ],
        "vagons" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("594a6a42231e5912342ff903"),
                        "numvag" : "01K",
                        "seatcount" : "30",
                        "reserves" : [
                                {
                                        "numseats" : "1-10",
                                        "numreserve" : "1",
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("594a6a42231e5912342ff904")
                                }
                        ],
                        "date2" : ISODate("2017-06-30T00:00:00Z"),
                        "date1" : ISODate("2017-06-05T00:00:00Z")
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("594a6c0d231e5912342ff905"),
                        "numvag" : "02C",
                        "seatcount" : "01-10",
                        "reserves" : [
                                {
                                        "numseats" : "01-10",
                                        "numreserve" : "05",
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("594a6c0d231e5912342ff906")
                                }
                        ],
                        "date2" : ISODate("2017-06-21T00:00:00Z"),
                        "date1" : ISODate("2017-06-25T00:00:00Z")
                }
        ],
        "date2" : ISODate("2017-07-30T00:00:00Z"),
        "date1" : ISODate("2017-06-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("594a69c4231e5912342ff900"),
        "trainnum" : "012A",
        "startplace" : "Tashkent",
        "destination" : "Samarkand",
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-06-21T12:42:44.893Z"),
        "weeks" : [
                "1",
                "2",
                "3",
                "4"
        ],
        "vagons" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("594b54fe0925d110180abf7b"),
                        "numvag" : "01K",
                        "seatcount" : "30",
                        "reserves" : [ ],
                        "date2" : ISODate("2017-07-23T00:00:00Z"),
                        "date1" : ISODate("2017-06-30T00:00:00Z")
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("594b55ede16d1908b8129b42"),
                        "numvag" : "02L",
                        "seatcount" : "40",
                        "reserves" : [ ],
                        "date2" : ISODate("2017-07-11T00:00:00Z"),
                        "date1" : ISODate("2017-06-29T00:00:00Z")
                }
        ],
        "date2" : ISODate("2017-07-30T00:00:00Z"),
        "date1" : ISODate("2017-06-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
```

How can I retrieve trains with all vagons which have date1 (vagons date1) > current day(22.06.2017) (Vagons.date1>current day). The result should be something like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("594a441fcbd8f815dc42436d"),
"trainnum" : "011Ф",
"startplace" : "Tashkent",
"destination" : "Samarkand"        
"weeks" : [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3"
    ],
    "vagons" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("594a6c0d231e5912342ff905"),
                    "numvag" : "02C",
                    "seatcount" : "01-10",
                    "reserves" : [
                            {
                                    "numseats" : "01-10",
                                    "numreserve" : "05",
                                    "_id" : ObjectId("594a6c0d231e5912342ff906")
                            }
                    ],
                    "date2" : ISODate("2017-06-21T00:00:00Z"),
                    "date1" : ISODate("2017-06-25T00:00:00Z")
            }
    ],
    "date2" : ISODate("2017-07-30T00:00:00Z"),
    "date1" : ISODate("2017-06-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
`{
    "_id" : ObjectId("594a69c4231e5912342ff900"),
    "trainnum" : "012A",
    "startplace" : "Tashkent",
    "destination" : "Samarkand",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-06-21T12:42:44.893Z"),
    "weeks" : [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4"
    ],
    "vagons" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("594b54fe0925d110180abf7b"),
                    "numvag" : "01K",
                    "seatcount" : "30",
                    "reserves" : [ ],
                    "date2" : ISODate("2017-07-23T00:00:00Z"),
                    "date1" : ISODate("2017-06-30T00:00:00Z")
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("594b55ede16d1908b8129b42"),
                    "numvag" : "02L",
                    "seatcount" : "40",
                    "reserves" : [ ],
                    "date2" : ISODate("2017-07-11T00:00:00Z"),
                    "date1" : ISODate("2017-06-29T00:00:00Z")
            }
    ],
    "date2" : ISODate("2017-07-30T00:00:00Z"),
    "date1" : ISODate("2017-06-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) condition on the field. Use [`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) for the `"cond"` argument.

If you don't have MongoDB 3.4 or greater, then use [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) instead of [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) and simply include all the other fields in the projection:

```
Train.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "vagons.date1": { "$gte": new Date("2017-06-22") }
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "vagons": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$vagons",
        "as": "v",
        "cond": { "$gt": [ "$$v.date1", new Date("2017-06-22") ] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Gives the output:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("594a441fcbd8f815dc42436d"),
        "trainnum" : "011Ф",
        "startplace" : "Tashkent",
        "destination" : "Samarkand",
        "weeks" : [
                "1",
                "2",
                "3"
        ],
        "vagons" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("594a6c0d231e5912342ff905"),
                        "numvag" : "02C",
                        "seatcount" : "01-10",
                        "reserves" : [
                                {
                                        "numseats" : "01-10",
                                        "numreserve" : "05",
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("594a6c0d231e5912342ff906")
                                }
                        ],
                        "date2" : ISODate("2017-06-21T00:00:00Z"),
                        "date1" : ISODate("2017-06-25T00:00:00Z")
                }
        ],
        "date2" : ISODate("2017-07-30T00:00:00Z"),
        "date1" : ISODate("2017-06-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("594a69c4231e5912342ff900"),
        "trainnum" : "012A",
        "startplace" : "Tashkent",
        "destination" : "Samarkand",
        "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-06-21T12:42:44.893Z"),
        "weeks" : [
                "1",
                "2",
                "3",
                "4"
        ],
        "vagons" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("594b54fe0925d110180abf7b"),
                        "numvag" : "01K",
                        "seatcount" : "30",
                        "reserves" : [ ],
                        "date2" : ISODate("2017-07-23T00:00:00Z"),
                        "date1" : ISODate("2017-06-30T00:00:00Z")
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("594b55ede16d1908b8129b42"),
                        "numvag" : "02L",
                        "seatcount" : "40",
                        "reserves" : [ ],
                        "date2" : ISODate("2017-07-11T00:00:00Z"),
                        "date1" : ISODate("2017-06-29T00:00:00Z")
                }
        ],
        "date2" : ISODate("2017-07-30T00:00:00Z"),
        "date1" : ISODate("2017-06-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: Works correctly. But it returns only _id and vagons fields. How can I add rest of the fields (trainnum, startplace, destination, weeks)? And can I add some condition for theese fields (trainnum, startplace ...)?

Comment: @Frank I'm using `$addFields` here because all that will do is "overwrite" the `"vagons"` field and replace it with the filtered content. If your MongoDB version is less than 3.4 and you do not have that pipeline operator, then `$project` must include **"all"** the fields. i.e `{ "$project": { "trainnum": 1, "startplace": 1 ... }` etc. But I did say that in the answer.

Comment: got that!. How can I add conditions for weeks field in this aggregation

Comment: @Frank try and adapt what you have here. If you still cannot work it out then [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). It's the clearest way. All questions that differ from your original are new questions anyway.